# lm and time series formats - is conversion necessary?

Tags: r

I want the slope from a couple of columns that looks like so:

```
date    time
7/8/2014    23.4917166
7/9/2014    28.69671107
7/10/2014   27.3262166
7/11/2014   30.25426663
7/12/2014   29.8345944
7/13/2014   27.7473055
7/14/2014   29.8657722
7/15/2014   29.2622055
```

The problem is, lm() doesn't seem to play ball with date in a mm/dd/yyyy format. If I make the date data numeric like so:

```
date    time
1   23.4917166
2   28.69671107
3   27.3262166
4   30.25426663
5   29.8345944
6   27.7473055
7   29.8657722
8   29.2622055
```

and run something like

```
timetest <- read.table("clipboard", sep="\t", header=T)
test <- lm(time ~ date, data=timetest)
coefficients(test)[2]
```

I get:

```
    date 
0.5605038
```

So how should I go about transforming the mm/dd/yyyy date format into something numeric? Is there a function to cast them as unix time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the as.POSIXct() wasn't working, so I went with:

```
timetest <- read.table("clipboard", sep="\t", header=T)

timetest$date <- as.numeric(as.Date(timetest$date, "%m/%d/%Y"))

test <- lm(time ~ date, data=timetest)
coefficients(test)[2]
```

Where the new 2nd line just overwrites the original m/d/y data with numeric values. Unix time not necessary for this process.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert first the date field to a Date specifying the format used (MM/DD/YYYY eq %m/%d/%Y), then `lm` does the conversion for you:

```
timetest$new_date <- as.Date(timetest$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

So, the regression looks like

```
test <- lm(time ~ new_date, data = timetest)
coefficients(test)[2]
```

and gives

```
as.numeric(new_date) 
           0.5605038
```

Note that `as.numeric` turns the date into the number of days since 1970-01-01

```
as.numeric(timetest$new_date[1])
[1] 16259
```

and

```
difftime(timetest$new_date[1], as.Date("1970-01-01"))
Time difference of 16259 days
```

You can also use `predict` to obtain new value for dates in the format of the original field

```
predict(test, data.frame(new_date = 
  seq.Date(as.Date("7/16/2014", format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    as.Date("7/20/2014", format = "%m/%d/%Y"), by = 1)))
```

that returns

```
       1        2        3        4        5 
30.83212 31.39262 31.95312 32.51363 33.07413
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your dates into Unix time, you can use something like

```
unix_time<-as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
```

but the values will end with a lot of zeros, so I'm not sure how useful they'll be in a regression.