# Unable to get R to display regression line (geom_smooth)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

Evening all, hoping someone can help. I've spent the evening messing around with the ggplot package, but for some reason, I cannot get a regression line to show up using geom_smooth!

I've included the code here, unfortunately, the terminal doesn't actually flag it as an error however which is part of the reason why I'm stumped! I've run it line by line and each line executes with no flags. The graph itself even appears without a hitch, just missing the regression line!

code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ScatterPlot <- ggplot(graph, aes (x= Specimen.date, y= Daily.lab.confirmed.cases)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))

ScatterPlot + ylim(0,5000) + labs(x = "Date") + labs(y = "Daily Cases")
```

output:

```
> ScatterPlot <- ggplot(graph, aes (x= Specimen.date, y= Daily.lab.confirmed.cases)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
> ScatterPlot + ylim(0,5000) + labs(x = "Date") + labs(y = "Daily Cases")
```

`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'

I've also tried converting columns to numeric but that didn't seem to work either ( x = as.numeric(***), y = as.numeric(***).

any suggestions!?

Thank you

Michael

Comment: Try `method = "lm"` instead of `method = lm`

Comment: No joy i'm afraid, thanks though!

Comment: Tricky! If geom_smooth isn't working, you could try plotting the lm directly - see example by jim89 here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/insert-regression-model-into-ggplot2/2439/7 Good luck!!

Comment: please add sample data of **graph**.

Comment: did you try geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y~x, se = FALSE)

Comment: @Mohanasundaram, No joy with this one i'm afraid. Thanks though!

Comment: Hi Michael, can you please post an image of your plot output by editing your question?  What you have labeled as "output" is a duplicate of your code above it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, we got there in the end. Mlcyo (See comments, Thanks!) got most of the way. Gave me a more helpful error at least. Heres how it was amended...:

```
graph[] <- lapply(graph, as.numeric) # Force entire dataframe into numeric type


fit <- lm(Daily.lab.confirmed.cases ~ Specimen.date, data = graph) # Manually generate linear model 

 geom_line(data = fortify(fit), aes(x = Specimen.date, y = .fitted)) # Insert after geom_point()
```

Hope it helps someone else! Thanks again mlcyo, good luck with the PhD!

M

Comment: Hi and glad you were able to get the plot to show... but it's not clear what was wrong in your initial case.  You should be able to get the line to show with `geom_smooth` as well.  Were you able to get the `geom_smooth` way of plotting the line to work after forcing the entire dataframe into numeric?  Also, what was the output of `str(graph)` *prior* to doing your `graph[] <- lapply(...)` line in the answer?  Was it one column in particular which was not numeric (but should have been)?

Comment: Glad you got it working Michael - for your original model did you check that the date object was converted correctly? I was running a lm with x=date last night and had some weird things happen - some tips here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098324/lm-and-time-series-formats-is-conversion-necessary